# getting similar output to cat when processing binary file

Tags: linux, bash, expect, cat

I created bash script to backup a lot of different switches using expect.
Because for example command `show config current_config` on D-Link switches displays one line after another too slow (like 1-2 lines per second, when there is more that 1000 lines) I decide to enable clipagaing and when switch ask for reaction I use loop like this:

```
for {} {1} {} {
expect -exact "CTRL" {send -- " "} -exact "DES-3028:" {send -- "logout\r"}}
```

or send -- "\r" for Enter (one line) instead of space (one page)

When I use that loop backing up one switch takes less than 5 seconds but in output I get lot of lines containing switch questions what to do.

When I open file created by expect in vim I see lines like:

```
^M ^[[7mCTRL+C^[[0m ^[[7mESC^[[0m ^[[7mq^[[0m Quit \
^[[7mSPACE^[[0m ^[[7mn^[[0m Next Page ^[[7mENTER^[[0m Next Entry \
^[[7ma^[[0m All ^M^@ ^M^@^[[1Aconfig loopdetect port 1 state enabled
```

When I do cat file1 I get

```
config loopdetect port 1 state enabled
```

that's what I want to get

When I do cat file1 > file2 I get exact copy of file1

Here you have example file https://www.dropbox.com/s/wo0usn8cfja7dbo/przyklad

Try to cat it and cat it to another file. I want effect of cat to screen but to another file.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to know why `show config current_config` takes so long to send you the output. Is it also slow when you log in via SSH and run the command? If you redirect the output to a file on the box. I.e. is the *command* slow or *sending the data to you*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a HTTP page where you can download the whole config as a file.

Use a tool like `wget` or `curl` to download the file from a script.

Comment: That's not the option. I wont connect to hundreds of switches one after another by HTTP :) . Bash script connect to one switch after another using ssh or telnet. Expect log output to file and I get that what portion I showed up in example link.

Comment: If you can connect by `ssh`, why don't you simply download the config file using `scp`?

Comment: And I don't see how connecting via SSH or HTTP is such a huge difference that you reject it outright. What's wrong with HTTP?

Comment: @AaronDigulla You don't seem to understand the problem at hand. OP uses SSH to log into *switches* with proprietary software. The configuration is almost certainly neither served via an inbuilt web server nor is it possible to just simply `scp` it over (usually there's a command to tell the device to upload its config via TFTP). That's why tools like [`rancid`](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) exist in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for not answering fast enough. When you write about scp I was enlightened - why do I display all configuration using expect and working on expect log and not just send upload cfg_toTFTP with expect and started to look for upload to tftp command on another switches. So yes your answers was useful. Thank you. As it comes to HTTP I just have it disabled in all switches. So my problem probably is gone if only all switches have upload to tftp or some other way to get config file from it.

Comment: But out of curiosity is there a way to do that what I was trying to do earlier - getting same thing that cat puts on screen to another file using cat file1 > file2 ? Thank you Aaron for enlightening me and yes Adrian you have the point.

Comment: @vonom: There is no simple way to strip the all the escape codes. There is [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) but as I understand it, that only strips the color changes. In your case, there is text that is printed on top of each other which you need to get rid of as well.

Comment: @Aaron Yes. Removing only escape codes can be done with some regexp but now I am just curious why cat file1 prints on screen only useful text (what process that text that we don't see escape codes and text in it - let say hidden text) and cat file1 > file2 copies all. What process text printed to screen by cat? Something like that. And I know about cat -A. I just want opposite way but to another file (like cat !-A file1 > file2 ;) ).

Comment: @vonom: Your "screen" is in fact a terminal program which executes the escape sequences. That's how they "vanish": The terminal will print a line with the "Quit Next..." and then move the cursor to the start of the line and print the config option over that, so you won't see it anymore.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thank you for explanation. Now I get it. I'll read a little more about that.